# How to fix Python error : "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'id1' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a little game with python. I have made this code :

```
def create_ennemy() :
    x = 1200
    y = randint(0, 650)
    t = randint(1, 5)
    if t <= 4 :
        id1 = c.create_polygon(7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 37.5, 52.5, 22.5, fill='red')
        r = 22.5
    elif t == 5 :
        c.create_polygon(7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 75, 105, 45, fill='red')
        r = 45
        ennemy_list.append(id1)
        ennemy_type.append(t)
```

But I get the following error :

> File "Jeux-d-avions.py", line 71, in create_ennemy
>       ennemy_list.append(id1) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'id1' referenced before assignment

I searched on the internet but it did not solve my problem. Why my code is not working?

Comment: Fix the indentation, please.

Comment: if `t > 4` then `id1` never exists so you cant add it to the list.

Comment: I guess the problem is the line right after your `elif`. It should probably read `id1 = c.create_polygon(7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 75, 105, 45, fill='red')`, but it's unclear due to missing indentation.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, there is no assignment of `id1` in the case of `elif`

I guess what you mean should be as follows:

```
 def create_ennemy() :
    x = 1200
    y = randint(0, 650)
    t = randint(1, 5)
    if t <= 4 :
        id1 = c.create_polygon(7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 37.5, 52.5, 22.5, fill='red')
        r = 22.5
    elif t == 5 :
        id1 = c.create_polygon(7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 75, 105, 45, fill='red')
        r = 45
    ennemy_list.append(id1)
    ennemy_type.append(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in your code, you just need to indent your code and a minor change to assign `id1`.

```
def create_ennemy() :
    x = 1200
    y = randint(0, 650)
    t = randint(1, 5)
    if t <= 4 :
        id1 = c.create_polygon(7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 37.5, 52.5, 22.5, fill='red')
        r = 22.5
    elif t == 5 :
        id1 = c.create_polygon(7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 75, 105, 45, fill='red')
        r = 45

    ennemy_list.append(id1)
    ennemy_type.append(t)
```

this will fix you mentioned error.